# Does it make sense to verify if values are different in a setter

Tags: c++, performance

I remember I saw somewhere (probably in Github) an example like this in a setter:

```
void MyClass::setValue(int newValue)
{
    if (value != newValue) {
        value = newValue;
    }
}
```

For me it doesn't make a lot of sense, but I wonder if it gives any performance improvement.

Comment: Seems to me like the performance might even be worse. Assuming your data is normally distributed, you will be doing an unnecessary if-check most of the time.

Comment: Follow up question, would a compiler optimize this out for the case of an `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deeper the instruction pipeline (and it only gets deeper and deeper on Intel platform at least), the higher the cost of a [branch misprediction](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/amplifierxe/lin/ug_docs/GUID-F239D74A-241D-4D21-81A4-1B5E95E6CAAA.htm).

> When a branch mispredicts, some instructions from the mispredicted
>   path still move through the pipeline. All work performed on these
>   instructions is wasted since they would not have been executed had the
>   branch been correctly predicted

So yes, adding an `if` int he code can actually hurt performance. The write would be L1 cached, possibly for a long time. If the write has to be visible then the operation would have to be interlocked to start with.

Answer (score 7):

It have no sense for `scalar types`, but it may have sense for some `user-defined` types (since type can be really "big" or its assignment operator can do some "hard" work).

Comment: That's true if the user-defined type is a `l-value reference`, but if it's not, you're probably better off doing a move (without the check)

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can really tell is by actually testing the different alternatives (benchmarking and/or profiling the code). Different compiler, different processors and different code calling it will make a big difference.

In general, and for "simple" data types (int, double, char, pointers, etc), it won't make sense. It will just make the code longer and more complex for the processor [at least if the compiler does what you ask of it - it may realize that "this doesn't make any sense, let's remove this check - I wouldn't rely on that tho' - compilers are often smarter than you, but making life more difficult for the compiler almost never leads to better code].

Edit: Additionally, it only makes GOOD sense to compare things that can be easily compared. If it's difficult to compare the data in the case where they are equal (for example, long strings take a lot of reads from both strings if they are equal [or strings that begin the same, and are only different in the last few characters]. So there is very little saving. The same applies for a class with a bunch of members that are often almost all the same, but one or two fields are not, and so on. On the other hand, if you have a "customer data" class, that has an integer customer ID that must be unique, then comparing just the customer id will be "cheap", but copying the customer name, address, phone number(s), and other data on the customer will be expensive. [Of course, in this case, why is it not a (smart) pointer or reference?]. End Edit.

If the data is "shared" between different processors (multiple threads accessing the same data), then it may help a little bit [in particular if this value is often read, and often written with the same value as before]. This is because "kicking out" the old value from the other processor's caches is expensive, and you only want to do that if you ACTUALLY change something.

And of course, it only makes ANY sense to worry about performance when you are working on code that you know is absolutely on the bleeding edge of the performance hot-path. Anywhere else, making the code as easily readable and as clear and concise as possible is always the best choice - this will also, typically, make the compiler more able to determine what is actually going on and ensure best optimization results.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is common in Qt, where the API is highly based on [signals & slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots). This pattern helps to avoid infinite looping in the case of cyclic connections.

In your case, where signals aren't present, this code only kills performance, as pointed out by @remus-rusanu and @mats-petersson.